# Why does a WHERE clause with an indexed, computed datetime column on an indexed view seek the clustered index on the original table

Tags: sql-server, materialized-view, azure-sql-database

First, sorry for the long title.

### The setup

I reduced the example to the minimum, to make it clearer, so there is no meaningful semantic anymore.

DBMS: **Azure SQL Database V12**.

Assume there is following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MuchDataTable](
    [SmallDateTimeColumn] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
)

GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MuchDataTable_SmallDateTimeColumn] ON [MuchDataTable] ([SmallDateTimeColumn])
```

Now I want to get aggregated data specific for a range of an arbitrary amount of days. As the table contains a lot of rows (over 150 Mio.) I created an indexed view, which looks basically like following:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AggregatedDateView]
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [SmallDateTimeColumn]) AS [DateColumn], COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Count]
    FROM [dbo].[MuchDataTable]
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, [SmallDateTimeColumn])

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AggregatedDateView_Date] ON [dbo].[AggregatedDateView] ([DateColumn])
```

For my day grouping I convert each `DateTime` to a `Date`. Then I create an clustered index over the view.

### The problem

Executing a simple SELECT * over the view scans the index of the view. That's fine:

[image: Execution plan for SELECT * FROM [AggregatedDateView]]

However, if I query with a WHERE constraint on the computed date column, a clustered index seek on the original table is performed:

[image: Execution plan for SELECT * FROM [AggregatedDateView] WHERE [DateColumn] = '2016-05-20']

### The question

My understanding is, that there should be a B-Tree consisting of all converted dates for the indexed view. **Why does SQL Server choose to scan the clustered index of the underlying table?** Is this not possible with an indexed view and I have to build a solution atop of triggers and a normal table?

**Edit**: for more clarification, it becomes a real problem, once a range of dates is scanned, so something like

```
SELECT * FROM [AggregatedDateView] WHERE [DateColumn] > '2016-05-20' AND [DateColumn] < '2016-08-20'
```

Here the index over 3 months is scanned, which is in my case already a lot.

Comment: Relevant: [Does Azure SQL DB support automatic indexed views?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqlemea/2016/09/04/does-azure-sql-db-support-automatic-indexed-views/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server expands the view and considers accessing the base tables instead. If the view or the base tables are used is a cost based decision by the optimizer.

To force SQL Server to use your indexed view you should use the [noexpand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx#Using%20NOEXPAND) hint.

```
SELECT * 
from [AggregatedDateView] WITH(NOEXPAND) 
where [DateColumn] > '2016-05-20' AND 
      [DateColumn] < '2016-08-20'
```